# angular 2 ng2-nvd3 undefined directive nvD3

Tags: angular, npm, nvd3.js, angular2-directives, ng2-nvd3

I am trying to implement graph as in this plunker: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview)

Here is the github code: [github](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3)

But I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  directives: [nvD3],
  template: 
    <div>
      <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
    </div>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use directives on A recent angular2,
directives should be configured in @NgModule
See this:
[angular-2-ngmodules](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-ngmodules/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way to declare directives using NgModule..

```
import { nvD3 } from 'ng2-nvd3'

@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        nvD3
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!